# How to use SP Service Account to add an item (with object model)?

Tags: 2007, event-handlers, runwithelevatedprivileges

1. I can add an item to SharePoint (with the object model) when I am logged in to SharePoint with an administrative account.
2. However, if I change to another user who is NOT listed in the backend SQL server database then the item add fails.
3. I get access failed. The log states it has to do with that user not being in the SQL server database.
4. That's why I need to use the service account in order to add an item to the SharePoint site with the object model.
5. I tried using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   but am still getting same error.

Anyone???

Comment: What do you mean with a user 'not being listed' in the backend SQL Server database? Can you include the relevant entries from the Windows Application and Security Event logs?

Answer (score 3):

Besides getting the logs as Jeroen suggests, please also include details on what type of project you are creating, and the context in how you access SharePoint (eg. event handler, timer job, console application, web part).

If you run in context of the IIS SharePoint will impersonate your user. That means that all database access runs in context of the application pool user, so SQL exceptions shouldnt be related to your current user not having access to SQL.

If you for example in a web part use the object model to retrieve items that your current user does not have access to in SharePoint, it will give you a security exception.

What running with elevated privileges does, is switching context to disable impersonation, so for that to work you need to run impersonated in the first place. This is why RWEP will not work when you are not running in IIS context (again like a web part).

Also RWEP has some [issues](http://daniellarson.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D3543C5837291E93!2005.entry), so be careful when using it and be sure you understand **why** you are using it, or you are better off first investigating why your code fails in the first place.

Another option is using SPUserToken for impersonation. Read more about this [here](http://daniellarson.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D3543C5837291E93!1993.entry) and [here](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/).

Again: tell us a bit more about what you want to achieve and how you are going about implementing it, to make us help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a new Instance of the SPWeb inside the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(..)` block?  If you aren't the code you're running will still use the original users credentials because the SPWeb (or SPSite) objects hold onto the permissions they were created with.

```
private void Example(SPWeb web)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
        // this will fail for normal users because the web is
        // holding onto the credentials it was created with  
        web.BreakRoleInheritance(false);  

        using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
        using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
        {
            // This one should work
            elevatedWeb.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
        }
    });        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great said guys. Here are the details.....

It's a C#, 3.5 framework, vs2008, class project.
2. Event hander used is "ItemUpdated"
3. I added SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
4. I am also creating a folder in the current document library - this piece works fine.
5. Then I use this code to make my folder read only but it's giving this error.    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I understand the test user does not have rights to make this folder read only. But I thought runwithprivileges takes care of issues like this. if not, how do I handle this.

```
    private void FolderReadOnly(SPWeb web, SPListItem folder)
    {
        if (!folder.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            //Setting false erases all permissions, so now the folder is hidden from everyone.
            folder.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
            folder.SystemUpdate(false);
        }
        SPRoleDefinition role = web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];
        SPGroupCollection collGroups = web.SiteGroups;
        foreach (SPGroup group in collGroups)
        {
            SPPrincipal principal = group;
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssign = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
            roleAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(role);
            folder.RoleAssignments.Remove(principal);
            folder.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssign);
            folder.SystemUpdate(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I post a working code shortly. Stand by.....

Answer (score 0):

**Still the same issue.** All the codes is under RunWithElevatedPrivileges. Code breaks at this line  folder.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

Error is shown below...

Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ResetSecurityScope(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjUrl, Guid guidDoc, Boolean bUnique, Boolean bCopyRoleAssignments, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32& piError)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObjectImpl.RevertRoleInheritance(Boolean copyRoleAssignments)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObjectImpl.BreakRoleInheritance(Boolean CopyRoleAssignments)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(Boolean CopyRoleAssignments)
   at ItemLevelPermissions.clAddPermissions.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()